# Help to porting function prototype -> jquery 1.4

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

I'm not an expert of jquery and i need help to porting this function

```
auto_complete: function(controller, focus) {
if (this.autocompleter) {
  Event.stopObserving(this.autocompleter.element);
  delete this.autocompleter;
}
this.autocompleter = new Ajax.Autocompleter("auto_complete_query", "auto_complete_dropdown", "/admin/" + controller + "/auto_complete", {
  frequency: 0.25,
  afterUpdateElement: function(text, el) {
    if (el.id) {
      window.location.href = "/admin/" + controller + "/" + escape(el.id);
    } else {
      $("auto_complete_query").value = "";
      window.location.href = window.location.href;
    }
  }
});
$("auto_complete_dropdown").update("");
$("auto_complete_query").value = "";
if (focus)
  $("auto_complete_query").focus();
```

},

Anyone may help me?

Comment: We are not here to do your job. If you have concrete question like "whats the equivalent of prototype foo() in jQuery" let us know. Also: why do you need to port this to a framework that you don't know anything about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although that uses some Prototype calls, that's actually mostly just using a [script.aculo.us](http://script.aculo.us) auto-completer; you'll want to find a similar widget for jQuery (there's [one listed](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete) on the jQuery plug-ins page) and then rewrite the code to do the same thing using that plug-in. Looks like mostly what it does is navigate to "/admin/mumble/id" where "mumble" is the value of the pass-in `controller` variable and "id" is the ID of the element chosen in the auto-completer.